# Path and paths of IO and NIO in java

Tags: java, path, classpath, java-io

I'm new at learning about IO and NIO in Java.

And I wonder what

- is the difference between `java.nio.file.Path` and `java.nio.file.Paths` ?
- is the difference between `Path` and `Paths`?

Thank for any explaining.

Comment: [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) and [Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html).

Comment: @Songs Please pay close attention to your package names.  There is no "stream based io" or `java.io.file.Paths` class.  The "new IO" which contains "block based io" transfers is under `java.nio.file.Paths`.  Basically the "New IO" adds two things to Java: Block based transfer, and a robust Path system.  The old "java.io" system has a Path system mostly built on String manipulation and a File concept (where the File doesn't need to exist, and can be a directory).

Answer (score 2):

Path is a class that represents a path.  Anything where you typically already have a `Path` involves the methods located here.

Paths is a set of utilities.  These utilities produce `Path` objects from other types of input.  The utilities do not require having a `Path` ahead of time.  They are convenience wrappers for common, often repeatedly used code, to reduce the need to cut-and-paste.

Here is an example of using `Paths`:

```
/* I have a String, but need a Path */
Path path = Paths.get("/home/user/.config");
```

Here is an example of using `Path`:

```
/* I have a Path, but need a String */
String name = path.toString();
```

The reason why a Utility class like `Paths` is required is a combination of a number of factors:

1. `Path` is an interface, so direct calls of its constructor are not possible; as it has no constructor.
2. `String` is a final class, and a class where modifying it would probably be far more difficult to present as an alternative than creating a utility class.  So while `"/home/user/.config".toPath()` might be a valid object-oriented way of doing things, legacy code prevents adding that without more deliberation.
3. `URI` has pressures on it similar to the pressures described above on `String`.

When they added in the NIO `Path` class, they wanted their code to be reviewed and integrated into the core Java library.

Stuff that is easy to get others to add to a library has the following characteristics:

1. You don't mess with existing parts of the library in ways that are exposed by the established library call interface (doing this disrupts users of the library, as now they need to rewrite their programs).
2. You have a backout plan that is easy (this is critical because you might not be able to deliver on time)

If they took the approach of modifying `String` and `URI` to have a `getPath(...)` function, then they would have increased the difficulty in getting their code integrated into the Java standard library.

Comment: Paths is a set if `utilities`, you refer to `import java.io.file.paths` ?

Comment: @Songs I am referring to `java.nio.file.Paths`  There is no paths under the "old" io/file package.  I also updated the question to give an idea of the pressures involved when working with an existing library.

Comment: Is Paths.get("/path/to/nfs") a blocking call? For example if NFS freezes up, would calling Paths.get() also freeze up?